# How to Trigger back the Jenkins job from the job who triggered it?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

[image: Scenario]

Here, three different jobs triggers the JOB X. Requirement is, on completion of JOB X, it should trigger back the job who triggered it.

For example, if JOB X is triggered by JOB B, it should trigger back only the JOB B.

Things I have tried:

1. I have used "build another job" option from Post build action, where I can mention the list of jobs needs to be triggered.
2. It is not satisfying my requirement as it is triggering all the JOBS listed in the box.

Kindly help !!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) :

1. Add a string parameter to your Job X, named `ParentJob` for example.
2. Use this parameter to configure the trigger of Job A, B or C : `${ParentJob}`
3. Add a post build action "Trigger parameterized builds on other projects" on each of your other jobs (A, B and C).
4. Add "Predefined parameters" to this post build action and pass the name of the job in the parameter `ParentJob` : `ParentJob=${JOB_NAME}`

Comment: The Post build Action should be added to JOB X not to the other JOBS right? Because, I want to trigger either JOB A or B or C from JOB X on its completion. When I list down all the project names (A B C) in "Projects to build" how jenkins know which of the projects should be triggered among the three ?

Comment: In Job A, B and C, you add a Post build Action with "Projects to build" set to "Job X" and with a "Predefined parameter" set to `ParentJob=${JOB_NAME}`. And in Job X you add a Post build Action with "Projects to build" set to `${ParentJob}`. But are you aware that this will create an infinite loop ? Job A triggers Job X that will trigger back Job A that will trigger again Job X, and so on...